# move active keys to align relative to selected key

Tags: graph-editor

My goal is to move all selected keys to "vertically align" with the left-most key.

[image]

I can approximate this with "Key >> Move, y" (g,y), and reasonably align these "by eye", I would like to have a bit more accuracy,  like applying `diff(value[frame1]-value[frame0])` to all frames[1-N].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom property for the selected item, use its gear icon to set it as Float, with appropriate values of min, max and precision; we will use this to temporarily store the value of the Y movement.

Select the target keyframe (in my example frame 40), hover over its value and press Ctrl C, then click on the custom property and press Ctrl V; delete the "m" suffix for meters, leaving  a pure float number.

Select the first frame of the moving part (60 in my example), copy its value, click on the custom property and type "-(Ctrl V)"; again delete the "m" suffix before validating with Enter.

Copy the value of the custom property on the clipboard with Ctrl C.

[image]

Set the graph editor timeline cursor on frame 60 and Ctrl click on the 70 number to select all keyframes from 60 and above, press G Y and move them a bit.

Open the black window dialog box on the bottom left (Adjust last operation), click on  Y and press Ctrl V to paste the value of the Y movement.

[image]

Comment: I'd skip the custom property and use a calculator app (or my fingers), but I see where the relative move coordinate box opens and that's my solution to enter a precise distance.  Thanks!  WIll give points for intelligence and handsomeness ;-)   Do you guys (you, moonboots, etc) ever get any work done besides being helpful)!